# Reducing the usage of HAD in past-perfect constructs

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

If I change the below excerpt

> In the secret study of Duchess Bianca Cappello, Agent Brüder **had
>   heard** a sickening thud followed by a growing commotion in the Hall
>   of the Five Hundred. He rushed to the grate in the wall and peered
>   through it. The scene on the elegant stone floor below took him
>   several seconds to process. The pregnant museum administrator **had
>   arrived** beside him at the grate, immediately covering her mouth in
>   mute terror at the sight below—a crumpled figure surrounded by
>   panicked tourists

to

> In the secret study of Duchess Bianca Cappello, Agent Brüder **had
>   heard** a sickening thud followed by a growing commotion in the Hall
>   of the Five Hundred. He **had rushed** to the grate in the wall and **peered**
>   through it. The scene on the elegant stone floor below took him
>   several seconds to process. The pregnant museum administrator **had
>   arrived** beside him at the grate, immediately covering her mouth in
>   mute terror at the sight below—a crumpled figure surrounded by
>   panicked tourists

1. Is the above excerpt correct?

2. **peered** is in past-simple because it is the current point-of-interest, the most recent action in the past. Is this correct?

3. The pregnant museum administrator **had arrived**. This happened before the agent peered. Is this correct?

4.Why do we past-perfect at all? Why not to use the below example. The sequence of events is pretty clear, first the agent heard, then he rushed and the he peered?

> In the secret study of Duchess Bianca Cappello, Agent Brüder **heard**
>   a sickening thud followed by a growing commotion in the Hall  of the
>   Five Hundred. He **rushed** to the grate in the wall and peered 
>   through it. The scene on the elegant stone floor below took him 
>   several seconds to process. The pregnant museum administrator **had
>   arrived** beside him at the grate, immediately covering her mouth in 
>   mute terror at the sight below—a crumpled figure surrounded by 
>   panicked tourists

Comment: There's no reason you have to use any past perfect in that paragraph, including the **had arrived** that you left in. And in fact, once you take out the **had heard**, the **had arrived** sounds wrong, because it happens after the **heard**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer some of your questions:

1. Is the above excerpt correct?
   It's perfectly natural English as spoken by native speakers. It might be marked down by an ESL teacher.
2. Is *peered* the current point-of-interest?
   I would say *took him several seconds to process* is the current point-of-interest. See below
3. Is it true that the pregnant museum administrator *had arrived* before the agent *peered*?
   This sequence of events doesn't make any sense, because she arrives *beside him* at the grate, and she can't do that before he's there. However, once the agent reaches the grate, he would naturally start peering immediately.
   But that's what we'd assume happened from the grammar if that sequence of events made sense. See below.

There's no reason you have to use any past perfect in that paragraph, including the **had arrived** that you left in.

However, once you take out the **had heard**, the **had arrived** sounds wrong, because it happens after the **heard**. So what is the point of the **had heard**?
It signals to the reader that the verbs aren't in linear order, so that you can use **had arrived** later in the paragraph and make it clear that the order is (in my interpretation):

> had heard a thud
>   rushed to the grate
>   peered through it
>   had arrived beside him
>   took him several seconds to process.

If you don't put any **had**s in, the reader assumes that the narrative is in linear order, and you get

> heard a thud
>   rushed to the grate
>   peered through it
>   took him several seconds to process
>   arrived beside him.

It is fairly clear from context that the museum administrator can't arrive beside him until after he has rushed to the grate and peered through it (because she would naturally go directly to the grate and not to beside him). If it wasn't clear from context, though, you would assume from the grammar that she arrived before he peered.

So why isn't it "**had** rushed to the grate and peered through it", as in your suggestion? (In this construction, the **had** before **rushed** also applies to **peered**.) We don't always put in the past perfect in a sequence of actions once we've established the time frame by putting the first verb in past perfect. This is undoubtedly lazy on our parts, and would probably be frowned upon by ESL teachers.

Comment: I am still a bit confused. As we said, past perfect is used to signal that something happened before some past action. If the order of past actions is clear then we don't need past perfect? But how about this: **once the door had been closed he approached me** or **they had won the game and had celebrated the victory by the time I arrived** In both examples the order of actions is very clear**the door close--> approach me** **win game --> celebrate --> I arrive**  Why not to use past simple in the above cases? Thank you

Comment: In the first one, I don't see any reason not to use the past simple.  In the second one, you probably need to use past perfect because of the clause *"by the time I arrived"*, which makes that time the reference time (which you call the current point-of-interest in the OP). But you could say *"They won the game and celebrated the victory before I arrived."*

Comment: Thanks for the answer Peter.  The two examples are very common constructs which I've been encountering in story books. The intriguing part for me is the usage of past perfect before past simple. It seems that the constructs with **by the time** always have **past perfect** - **by the time** - **past simple**, although for me it could have been constructed as past simple only, because **by the time** is same as **before**. May I ask you to elaborate more on this as you are a native speaker. Thanks!!

Comment: You're right, but I don't know if I can elaborate more. These probably fit into a larger set of grammatical rules, but I don't have them figured out in a way I can explain them.

Comment: I understand, it is simply a pattern. Thanks Peter